# пользователь вводит свой класс школы, а затем день недели, как сделать так, чтобы именно для этого класса выводилась расписание

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Вопрос в pyTelegramBotAPI. Нужно чтобы пользователь вводил номер класса и его букву, дальше понедельник, и именно какое расписание будет в этом классе

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])  # Номер класса и буква
def get_user_info(message):
    class_class = message.text
    if message.text == "7Д":
        bot.reply_to(message, f"Здорово! Далее пиши день недели, на который хочешь узнать расписание")
        if message.text == "Понедельник":
            bot.send_photo

    if message.text == "7Е":
        bot.send_photo

        bot.reply_to(message, f"Здорово! Далее пиши день недели, на который хочешь узнать расписание")
        if message.text == "Понедельник":
    if message.text == "8А":
        bot.send_photo

        bot.reply_to(message, f"Здорово! Далее пиши день недели, на который хочешь узнать расписание")
        if message.text == "Понедельник":
            bot.send_photo

    if message.text == "8Б":
        bot.reply_to(message, f"Здорово! Далее пиши день недели, на который хочешь узнать расписание")
        if message.text == "Понедельник":
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=open('C:/Users/yeeww/Desktop/8B_monday.jpg', 'rb'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой есть вариант

```
from telebot import TeleBot, types
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton


bot = TeleBot(...)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи номер класса')
    # теперь следующее сооющение от юезра обработается в get_class_number
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_class_number)


def get_class_number(message: types.Message):
    # проверка на число
    if message.text.isdigit():
        # делаем клавиатуру
        markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2).add(
            # делаем кнопки, с колбек датой, 
            # которая состоит из префикса get_weekday, по которому мы отслеживаем нажатие
            # день недели и номер класса, который ввел юзер
            InlineKeyboardButton("Понедельник", callback_data=f"get_weekday:monday:{message.text}"),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Вторник", callback_data=f"get_weekday:tuesday:{message.text}"),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Среда", callback_data=f"get_weekday:wednesday:{message.text}"),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Четверг", callback_data=f"get_weekday:thursday:{message.text}"),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Пятница", callback_data=f"get_weekday:friday:{message.text}"),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Суббота", callback_data=f"get_weekday:saturday:{message.text}"),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Воскресенье", callback_data=f"get_weekday:sunday:{message.text}"),
        )
        # отправляем
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Теперь выбери день недели", reply_markup=markup)
    else:
        # если не число то требуем заново ввести
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы ввели не число, повторите попытку')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_class_number)


# для инлайн кнопок нужны колбек хендлеры
# здесь мы получаем тот колбек дата которого начинается с get_weekday:
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data.startswith("get_weekday:"))
def get_weekday(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    # распаковываем колбек дату по двоеточию
    _, weekday, class_number = call.data.split(":")
    # в этот момент у тебя есть и день недели типа monday/tuesday ...
    # так и номер класса, введеный ранее



if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: не совсем понял)

Comment: @rmkhv что именно?

Comment: я только начинаю этот пакет изучать, почти совсем не понял, если так можем, мейби дискрод, объяснишь?

Comment: @rmkhv добавил комментарии